# HOW TO RETURN THE MOST RECENT VALUE?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

| timestamp | id | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-06-01T00:00:00 | ID1 | LOL |
| 2021-06-01T00:00:01 | ID2 | DOTA |
| 2021-06-01T00:00:02 | ID2 | DOTA |
| 2020-06-02T00:00:00 | ID5 | COD |
| 2020-06-02T00:00:01 | ID7 | VALO |
| 2020-06-02T00:00:02 | ID8 | VALO |
| 2020-06-02T00:00:03 | ID3 | DOTA |
| 2020-06-03T00:00:00 | ID1 | DOTA |
| 2020-06-03T00:00:01 | ID1 | DOTA |
| 2020-06-03T00:00:02 | ID2 | DOTA |
| 2020-06-03T00:00:03 | ID3 | DOTA |
| 2020-06-03T00:00:04 | ID4 | LOL |

I am trying to get a result for all DISTINCT IDS with the most recent type.

Using this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, type
FROM table1
ORDER BY 1;
```

I got this result:

| id | type |
| --- | --- |
| ID1 | DOTA |
| ID1 | LOL |
| ID2 | DOTA |
| ID3 | DOTA |
| ID4 | LOL |
| ID5 | COD |
| ID7 | VALO |
| ID8 | VALO |

I understand that the row 1 and row 2 have distinct values. I tried querying this to check if it will only return a value with the most recent date. It didn't.

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, type, MAX(timestamp) date
FROM table1
GROUP BY 1, 2
ORDER BY 1;
```

| id | type | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ID1 | DOTA | 2020-06-03 00:00:01 |
| ID1 | LOL | 2021-06-01 00:00:00 |
| ID2 | DOTA | 2021-06-01 00:00:02 |
| ID3 | DOTA | 2020-06-03 00:00:03 |
| ID4 | LOL | 2020-06-03 00:00:04 |
| ID5 | COD | 2020-06-02 00:00:00 |
| ID7 | VALO | 2020-06-02 00:00:01 |
| ID8 | VALO | 2020-06-02 00:00:02 |

Tried below query just to check. Returned the same.

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, type, (SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM table1 as b where b.timestamp = a.timestamp ) 
FROM table1 as a
GROUP BY 1, 2
ORDER BY 1;
```

Is my intended result possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below options

```
select as value array_agg(t order by timestamp desc limit 1)[offset(0)]
from `project.dataset.table1` t
group by id
```

or

```
select *
from `project.dataset.table1` t
where true 
qualify row_number() over(partition by id order by timestamp desc) = 1
```

both with below output

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. I think I was able to get the result I need. I decided to take the QUALIFY route as I found a good guide regarding the syntax. If it's not too much , can I ask what does the 'where true' and '=1' in the qualify clause means?

Comment: Meantime - where clause is a requirement for use of qualify clause

Comment: Actually I think I got it. Qualify would only work to expressions that are true. Hence, the where true statement. QUALIFY AND ROW_NUMBER are like two separate statements. '=1' returns only one value. And since the timestamp is ordered to be DESC, we got the 1st row to be the most recent value.

Comment: Still trying to get a hang of the website. Thought I could accept two answers.

Comment: consider also voting up the answer if it helped!

Answer (score 1):

A simple method uses `qualify`:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM chinook.new_table as a
WHERE true
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id, type ORDER BY date DESC) = 1;
```

You can also express this easily using `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(a ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1).*
FROM chinook.new_table a
GROUP BY id, type;
```

Answer (score 0):

This provides you groups:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, type, MAX(timestamp) date
FROM chinook.new_table as a
GROUP BY 1, 2
ORDER BY 1;
```

However, seemingly you want a single group for each `id`, so you will need to somehow aggregate `type` as well:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, GROUP_CONCAT(`type`), MAX(timestamp) date
FROM chinook.new_table as a
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

The above will group types into comma-separated values.

Answer (score 0):

Just use GROUP BY

```
SELECT id, type, MAX(date) AS date_max FROM table1 GROUP BY id,type ORDER BY id,type;
```